# Load a sheet from GDrive using API without logging in

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I need to load the contents of a public Google Sheet from a Javascript web-app, but I don't want people to have to log in to do this. The REST API works fine, but requires a Google login to load:

```
var str="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+id+"/export?
mimeType=text/tab-separated-values";
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();                                   
xhr.open("GET",str);
xhr.onload=function()  {  // do something;   };
xhr.send();
```

Normally, I auth-in before the above and it loads, but I want to make it more accessible. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From :

```
var str="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+id+"/export?mimeType=text/tab-separated-values";
```

#### To :

```
var str="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+id+"/export?format=tsv";
```

#### Note :

- In order to use this, please confirm whether the spreadsheet is shared again.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: @Bill Ferster Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved.